# Find :$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f(x^n) dx $?

Tags: real-analysis

> Given  $f$  is  continuous  on $[0,1]$ , Then $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f(x^n) dx  $$ is
>
> - $ f(1)$
> - $f(0)$
> - $1$
> - $0$

I thinks  it will be  $0$ because    $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^n dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1} = 0  $

Is its true ?

Comment: If you interchange the limit and integration, then also because $f$ is continuous, then we have $\int_{0}^1 f(\lim x^n) dx = \int_0^1 f(0) dx = f(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is $f(0)$ by DCT. A dominating integrable function is the supremum of $|f|$.

Comment: what is DCT   sir ?

Comment: @Messififa Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)=347, x\in [0,1]$, then the limit is 347. Thus, under the assumption that $347\neq 0$ your argument is incorrect.